React native custom font in 700 not working
I use Quicksand as custom font in react-native version 0.73.5. When I give all fonts, the values work. When font weight is set to 600 it works and i can give bold font if i want. But when font weight is 700 custom font doesn't work.
    <Text
      style={{
        color: STATIC_COLORS.WHITE,
        fontSize: 20,
        fontFamily: 'Quicksand-Bold',
        fontWeight: '700',
      }}>
      font test - don't work
    </Text>

An example like below works but I do not use react native text component directly in my project. I create my own component with text and use it. Font family is given in it.
Font family is not given in every text component. It is assigned only in the custom text component. When using this custom text component, we only adjust with weight. I cannot change this operation.
    <Text
      style={{
        color: STATIC_COLORS.WHITE,
        fontSize: 20,
        fontFamily: 'Quicksand-Bold',
        fontWeight: '600',
      }}>
      font test - work
    </Text>

In my custom text component, an assignment is made in this way.
'600': FONT_FAMILY.SEMIBOLD,
'700': FONT_FAMILY.BOLD,

If I give '700' as weight it will take the bold font but it doesn't work. I am sure I added the fonts properly. The bold example above works. As I said, I cannot get the bold value with the custom font only when 700 is given as weight.

I found the solution but I don't have detailed information about why.
I created the directory android/app/src/main/res/font and added the fonts' .otf files renamed with lowercase letters.
I also created an .xml file called font.
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<font-family xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <!--<font app:fontStyle="normal" app:fontWeight="300" app:font="@font/quicksand_light" />
    <font app:fontStyle="normal" app:fontWeight="400" app:font="@font/quicksand_regular" />
    <font app:fontStyle="normal" app:fontWeight="500" app:font="@font/quicksand_medium" />
    <font app:fontStyle="normal" app:fontWeight="600" app:font="@font/quicksand_semibold" />-->
    <font app:fontStyle="normal" app:fontWeight="700" app:font="@font/quicksand_bold" />
</font-family>

It got better when I added them, of course I only added the 700 one, the others were fine.
also, although I don't show the code completely here, I assign fonts with font weight in my text component. so 700 will actually always be equal to bold font.

This is issue with RN version 0.73.5. There are multiple issue with the same version so you can upgrade or downgrade your react native version. It will works fine for you.

I am facing similar issue in 0.75.2

If you are using react-native iOS then font-weight will work fine, but in react-native android you can't use font weight you should use particular font-weight of that font-family.
for example:
Roboto:
Roboto_thin 100
Roboto_thin 400
Roboto_thin 600
Roboto_thin 700
Roboto_thin 800
Roboto_thin 900
React-Native Example:
<Text
style={{
color: '#FFFFFF,
fontSize: 20,
fontFamily: 'Roboto_thin 700',
}}>

